# How to configure Nginx traffic to go through another proxy

Tags: nginx, networking, proxy

I have nginx configured to act as a reverse proxy

```
http {
log_format combined '$proxy_protocol_addr - $remote_user [$time_local] '
                    '"$request" $status $body_bytes_sent '
                    '"$http_referer" "$http_user_agent"';
#...

server {
    server_name localhost;

    listen 80   proxy_protocol;
    listen 443  ssl proxy_protocol;

    ssl_certificate      /etc/nginx/ssl/public.example.com.pem;
    ssl_certificate_key  /etc/nginx/ssl/public.example.com.key;

    location /app/ {
        proxy_pass       http://backend1;
        proxy_set_header Host            $host;
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP       $proxy_protocol_addr;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_protocol_addr;
    }
}
```

Something very similar to the example above.

But i need that all the traffic that is going to **backend** server will go through another proxy.

Meaning:

Client request -> Nginx (as reverese proxy) --- all traffic---> Proxy server -> backend server

Is it possible?